# PHP - shell_exec output in browser is empty

Tags: php, wget, shell-exec

I'm running a simple `wget` command in `shell_exec()`

**wget_file.php**

```
<?php
$command = "wget http://mydomain.co/media/bigbigbig.wav";
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

According to http://www.php.net/shell_exec I can possibly expect an output:
"The output from the executed command or NULL if an error occurred or the command produces no output."

If I run wget_file.php from the command line, I'll see a display of the wget results.
However, if I run it from a browser, no result is given.  (but the file does indeed download successfully)

I plan to execute the wget_file.php by calling via `cUrl`, while passing the url + path.
But would be nice to get a response from the `shell_exec()`, after execution is completed.

Does anyone know if I'm just missing something to get an output (running in the browser)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I run wget_file.php from the command line, I'll see a display of the wget results

`wget` doesn't output the file contents to console by default, so presumably you're talking about the status information.

I'd imagine this is output to STDERR rather than STDOUT, and it's STDOUT that `shell_exec` obtains for you in your PHP script:

- when you run your script from the command line, you're still seeing the output because *both* streams are shared by the single terminal window; it's just that you're seeing it directly from `wget` and not from your PHP script;
- in the case of passing it through Apache and to a browser to satisfy a web request, this terminal context is disconnected from the result the user sees.

In your shell command you can redirect the former to the latter:

```
$command = "wget http://mydomain.co/media/bigbigbig.wav 2>&1";
```

The comments on [the documentation for `shell_exec`](http://www.php.net/shell_exec) touch on this, particularly the — er — [very first one](http://www.php.net/shell_exec#106250)!

Comment: Nice explanation. I wasn't paying attention to the STDERR and STDOUT.